# Remove left padding

Tags: android, android-layout

> I added search view to toolbar.but there is small gap in Left side between LinearLayout and toolbar.I need to remove that padding.But I did not added any padding intentionally.How can I remove that?Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Drawer With Swipe Tabs"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editMobileNo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"

                android:background="@drawable/login_edittext"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textColorHint="@color/orange"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search2"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="0.96">
            </EditText>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/alarm3"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: is there any padding in `styles.xml`?

Comment: there is no padding in login_edittext drawable too?

Comment: no any padding.I need to remove left side gap between search bar.I need it to put in fully left side.without padding.

Comment: <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"

                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />

this is the padding which I put in login_edittext drawable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
.
.
.
.

android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" />
```

Add these to remove content Inset

Comment: Wow that is worked for me !.can you tell me what is the content Inset mean ?I'll mark this answer after 10 minutes.Thank you once again.

Comment: Minimum inset for content views within a bar. Navigation buttons and menu views are excepted. Only valid for some themes and configurations.As mentioned in official link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#top)